# MongoDB sort by multiple fields on boolean type

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

First of all i need `"isFavourite": true` then `"isReadByPro": false` and then `updatedAt:-1`.

I tried below way but not working.

```
{ $sort: { updatedAt: -1 } },
{ $sort: { isReadByPro: 1 } },
{ $sort: { isFavourite: -1 } },
```

```
[
            {
                "_id": "628c8378c92d4b969cf4b53b",
                "post": {
                    "title": "project 94608"
                },
                "isFavourite": true,
                "isReadByPro": true,
                "updatedAt": "2022-06-06T10:34:05.776Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "628f507192034120c7fc261a",
                "post": {
                    "title": "your payment test 1"
                },
                "isFavourite": true,
                "isReadByPro": true,
                "updatedAt": "2022-05-27T10:39:16.493Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "628f50a792034120c7fc2681",
                "post": {
                    "title": "your payment test 3"
                },
                "isFavourite": true,
                "isReadByPro": true,
                "updatedAt": "2022-05-27T08:42:48.403Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "628c76840ffe2cd088654d50",
                "post": {
                    "title": "showcase 1"
                },
                "isFavourite": false,
                "isReadByPro": true,
                "updatedAt": "2022-05-24T06:10:38.364Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "628c780a0ffe2cd088654e21",
                "post": {
                    "title": "project 1 test"
                },
                "isFavourite": false,
                "isReadByPro": true,
                "updatedAt": "2022-05-27T06:30:54.058Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "628c79cb5b4b0ee6020482df",
                "post": {
                    "title": "project 2 test"
                },
                "isFavourite": false,
                "isReadByPro": true,
                "updatedAt": "2022-05-27T06:30:54.058Z"
            }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to sort by multiple fields, they should be on the same sorting object. The order of them is according to priority. This data is sorted first by `isFavourite`, then, all the documents with the same `isFavourite` value will be sorted between them by `isReadByPro` and so on.

```
{ $sort: {isFavourite: -1, isReadByPro: 1, updatedAt: -1} }
```